# Efficient identification of an equation given inputs and outputs.

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

Looking for a more formal approach to identify factors of a given calculation and a way to approximate that equation itself.

I know of $x$ many inputs to a given calculation, and I have the output, but I don't have any good way to identify which inputs are actually used in the output. It may only use one of the inputs, it may use all of them, or anything in between. The simplest way is to modify only one input at a time but I don't have that luxury, they come as a set of values and cannot be adjusted individually (though there are many different sets of data from which to examine).

After identifying the factors, is there a good way to identify the equation itself? In this particular case (data below) I know there are two inputs but I don't have a formalised way to identify an equation for it. I have been trying various polynomial combinations and running it through excel solver to attempt to identify an equation that fits, but it has not been an efficient approach. I'd say a valid equation should be accurate up to 5 significant digits but its been difficult to do this with just trial and error.

| input 1 | input 2 | output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 61 | 16 | 0.233432051588249 |
| 61 | 18 | 0.2344106759016 |
| 61 | 19 | 0.234899689515166 |
| 61 | 20 | 0.235389300214951 |
| 65.6 | 16 | 0.239836497890295 |
| 65.6 | 18 | 0.240832674050633 |
| 65.6 | 19 | 0.241331091772152 |
| 65.6 | 20 | 0.24182885021097 |
| 74 | 16 | 0.251737360278333 |
| 74 | 18 | 0.252764823451033 |
| 74 | 19 | 0.253278555037382 |
| 74 | 20 | 0.253792286623732 |
| 77 | 16 | 0.256051361442492 |
| 77 | 18 | 0.257090428922685 |
| 77 | 19 | 0.257610417994718 |
| 77 | 20 | 0.258129496402878 |

Comment: You can obtain a function taht matches the datapoints exactly for example by defining a piecewice linear interpolation between precisely those data points. That's probably not what you want. Is there any underlying assumption that the relation should be poylnomial? Of some bounded degree? Such questions can only be answered if you already have some idea and model about the relation input-output. In your case, how do you even find those *extrenely* high-precision outputs to begin with?

Comment: based on other input/output pairings, they have all had polynomial solutions so I assume this one is no different in that regard. Other equations have been mostly simpler ax + by +c or similar formats, but this one simply doesnt conform. I've tried adding other factors for squares and the inverse of the inputs but I assume there are more combinations i've not tried. A more formal approach to use would be nice. as far as percision goes, I should have sanitized the numbers, they're only accurate up to 5-6 significant digits its just excel gives the full computed value when copy/pasting.

Comment: Again, what makes you even *suspect* that there is a simple relation between input and output? If the data comes from a statistic and e.g. says that the average income of a 61 year old person after 16 years in their job is 0,23343 million dollars, then there is good reason to expect a *correlation*, but little reason to expect a *simple* expression that produces the output in full (here: five-digit) precision and doesn't produce total garbage when interpolating (not to mention extrapolating) to new inputs

Comment: the output is a calculated result based on the inputs and no external data. A computer program reads the input and produces the output, simple as that. the output remains the same across diverse sets of input so long as these two factors are identical so it does seem to be directly correlated to these two inputs. is it possible to have an equation result that cannot be represented as a polynomial expansion? they may be complicated expressions in the expansion (x-y)/(x+y) for example but with no structured way to identify these, it has been difficult to chase down a valid solution

Answer (score 0):

A fast solution could be a [stepwise regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stepwise_regression) for a generalized linear model
$$z(x,y)=a_0+\sum_{i=1}^n a_i t_i$$  defining factors such as
$$\left\{x,y,\frac{1}{x},\frac{1}{y},x^2,x y,y^2,\frac{1}{x^2},\frac{1}{x
   y},\frac{1}{y^2},\frac{x}{y},\frac{y}{x},\cdots\right\}$$